# EditText inside TextInputLayout leaves empty space at the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have password field and i wanted to implement hide/show password functionality. So I used TextInputLayout. But if I use EditText inside TextInputLayout, it leaves empty space at the top of the layout. And I need to have height of that password field smaller. With that gap there, it's not possible. 
I've tried to set height to negative value for EditText, but it did not work.
android:layout_height="45dp" is used to make that field smaller, but it doesnt work at all. wrap_content makes it even taller.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/login_password_eye"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordTextField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDivider"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorItemMajor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Image:

[image]

XML Code - full (i had to remove colors and images + top toolbar, but logic is same)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLoginLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLogin"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailTextField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_password_padding"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_password_field_padding"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/login_password_eye"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@android:color/black">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordTextField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDivider"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorItemMajor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_password_label_textsize" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/default_login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/loginButtonIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LoginButtonLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textAppearance="@style/FilledLoginButtonTextAppearance" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you see this on layout preview . compile it try to run then
>   you see its working gud. this gap is because you use floating edit
>   text. – Harwinder Singh

This worked!

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextInputEditText` instead `EditText`

> A special sub-class of EditText designed for use as a child of TextInputLayout.
>
> Using this class allows us to display a hint in the IME when in
>   'extract' mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/login_password_eye"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordTextField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDivider"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorItemMajor"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"` to your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code related to your problem and its work properly in project. try this with your own way
**and don't forget to comment.**

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_Layout_Signup_Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_Layout_Signup_Phone"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_Signup_Password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: hey, send your whole xml file then i see and give solution to you

Comment: send me on photo of your layout xml code is write may be after see your  xml .i give you solution

Comment: I think you see this on layout preview . compile it try to run then you see its working gud. this gap is because you use floating edit text.

Comment: If you got solution plz give check right and vote up if you can

Answer (score 0):

add bottom padding to TextInputLayout

```
android:paddingBottom="11dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have done TextInputLayout to be fix with

```
 android:layout_height="45dp"
```

Please change to wrap_content

Comment: I did that intentionally to lower the actual height, because wrap_content makes it taller. But as I used wrap_content, gap is still there + it will not fix my gap issue